# How to connect to the QQ Messenger network?

Tags: instant-messaging

I´m looking for a version of QQ messenger for Ubuntu 12.04. I found a note in Wikipedia that there is a beta version of QQ for Linux, but I could't find it. Does anyone know where I can find it?
Are there any alternative messenger to use QQ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

There is a recently developed [plugin for Pidgin](https://github.com/xiehuc/pidgin-lwqq) that works quite well. Basic things such as chatting, buddyicons and sending files are all supported. You can use it by adding [`ppa:lainme/pidgin-lwqq`](https://launchpad.net/~lainme/+archive/pidgin-lwqq) to your repositories and then install `pidgin-lwqq`. After that WebQQ shows up in the list of protocols to choose from when adding a new account in Pidgin.

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lainme/pidgin-lwqq
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-lwqq
```

Comment: Dont waste your time, it doesn't work. Can't get it to login.

Comment: QQ has disable all 3rd party clients and APIs a couple years ago - only official Tencent releases work now AFAIK

Answer (score 3):

You can find the download page at http://im.qq.com/qq/linux/download.shtml or if you just want the direct link to the .deb package:

http://dl_dir.qq.com/linuxqq/linuxqq_v1.0.2-beta1_i386.deb

Comment: This is for common QQ in chinese. Sorry, my fault. I forgot to say I´m looking for QQ international in english or german language.
Or is only chinese verison available for linux?

Comment: @JensHN I think due to QQ being Chinese it might be the only version.

Comment: ok, thanks for your help. Next step. learnign chinese :-)

Comment: First, the .deb is crap, you can't install it. If you download the .tar.gz, it will run, but you can't login...

Answer (score 1):

Forget all about the linux version of QQ. It's so old that it doesn't work properly.  In fact, it never worked properly. As far as I am aware (I've been teaching in China for 10 years) QQ for linux was never properly developed in the first place and there certainly hasn't been any further development.

Yes, you can use longene/wine but to be perfectly honest, it's 'iffy' and buggy.  Bear in mind that whilst the front page of QQ will be in English -or the language of your choice - the remainder will be in Chinese .. the 'search for friends .. add contact..'  and the inbuilt translator is absent.

The best advice I can offer is to make your system dual-boot.  Install Windows then download QQ (www.imqq.com)  shove a Ubuntu cd into the drive and restart the computer.  Install Ubuntu alongside Windows.

If you want to use QQ boot into the Windows operating system.  Bear in mind that QQ International will install the front-end in your chosen language along with the inbuilt translator, but the back end - the 'QZone' for photos and blog will all be in Chinese.

I'm not the only 'foreign teacher' who has tried linux qq/longene etc ..  We've all settled on the dual boot system.

Comment: As an alternative to dual boot (especially if it is for just one tool with minor system requirements) some sort of virtualization could be used. For example Virtual Box, there is already an package for ubuntu and it is quite easy to use.

Comment: Sad, but true. I agree with Adaephon, VirtualBox. KVM is said to have better performance, but don't install that KVM krap, because your laptop will afterwards crash when it resumes from standby.

Comment: Dual booting for a game or Office makes some sense, but rebooting just to reply to a message seems very impractical...

Answer (score 1):

```
sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lainme/pidgin-lwqq
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pidgin-lwqq
```

**pidgin-lwqq** is the right way, it works for me without any problems. Had it running under Arch Linux. The Chinese prefer it to webqq, the wine thing or the old one from Tencent (does not work any more).

If you login, there is a little window popping up asking you for a captcha, that's it.   ;-)

Here http://www.xheike.com/thread-1442-1-1.html and here http://www.cnblogs.com/zhj5chengfeng/archive/2013/09/08/3308029.html one can see that it works. Okay, with a little Chinese knowledge.

Answer (score 0):

for your Linux needs please consider using:

http://qqchat.qq.com (QQ for Facebook.. it's wickedly good!)

Or in alternative you can always try your luck with WINE...

Comment: The web-chat doesn't work, the .deb doesn't install, the pidgin-extension can't login, the .tar.gz says it's too old and logs out, with the windows version on wine you can't enter the username or password. What a crap of a software.