# Can Ubuntu 13.10 use QQ International without wine?

Tags: wine

The Wine always crashes,so I don't want to use it.Can Ubuntu 13.10 use [QQ International](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tencent_QQ#QQ_International) without wine ?

Comment: ...Is QQ International a malware...

Comment: QQ International appears to be a *client program* rather than a *separate IM service*. Assuming that is the case, if your goal is just to connect to the QQ instant messaging service from Ubuntu, some of the answers at [How to connect to the QQ Messenger network?](http://askubuntu.com/q/253852/22949) may be relevant.

Comment: There are [criticisms about the way QQ is run](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tencent_QQ#Controversies_and_criticisms) that might worry some users. For example the Chinese version has adverts and the older versions of it were branded "adware"... And there's always the whole Chinese human-rights government-spying thing that people should be conscious of... But I can't definitively say that this is or isn't adware.

Comment: They're disgusting...QQ , 360 and other "malware"...I even don't know that those programs are or aren't "malwares" in China...

Comment: **For future visitors**: One of the possible alternatives is to install QQ under an android emulator, such as Genymotion. Steps described in an answer here: https://askubuntu.com/q/540875/295286

Answer (score 0):

Yes there is beta version of qq international package was available for download on Linux.

- Download the .deb file from [here](http://dl_dir.qq.com/linuxqq/linuxqq_v1.0.2-beta1_i386.deb).
- Move to the directory where .deb file was downloaded using `cd`.
- Install the .deb file by running the below command,

  ```
  sudo dpkg -i <packagename>.deb
  ```

[How to connect to the QQ Messenger network?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/253852/is-there-an-alternative-for-qq-messenger)

Comment: I can't install it because there is something wrong.                msy@msy-Inspiron-One-2020:~/下载$ sudo dpkg -i linuxqq_v1.0.2-beta1_i386.deb 
[sudo] password for msy: 
dpkg: error processing linuxqq_v1.0.2-beta1_i386.deb (--install):
 parsing file '/var/lib/dpkg/tmp.ci/control' near line 7 package 'linuxqq':
 版本字符串 v1.0.2-beta1 中有错误: version number does not start with digit
在处理时有错误发生：
 linuxqq_v1.0.2-beta1_i386.deb

Comment: just rename the file into linuxqq.deb and then try to install it.If any error occurs plz post it in pastebin and then provide the link here.

Comment: i386?My ubuntu is amd64.maybe I can't install it because of this difference .

Comment: see http://askubuntu.com/questions/359156/how-do-you-run-a-32-bit-program-on-a-64-bit-version-of-ubuntu

Comment: http://www.cnblogs.com/sunyubo/archive/2010/08/27/2282129.html

Answer (score 0):

qq is not supported in Linux at all anymore. The qq for Linux never left beta and in its current form doesn't work at all.

Your best bet for using qq under Linux, is to use the Chinese based distros, Linux Deepin (currently at 2014 version) or Ubuntu Kylin 14.04, and up.

These 2 distros have a working PC version of `wineqq` that work OK, but I haven't been able to get video or audio working on any system to date. Either that or web qq (which sucks) are your only options at this point for the fullest qq experience currently available.