# How to install QQ on Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: software-installation, instant-messaging

I'm a new learner of Ubuntu, installing Ubuntu 14.04 on my PC, but can't install QQ. How can I install it?

Comment: 好像是在software center 有 但是我常识用的时候不可以log in. 你可以尝试Ubuntu Kylin, 这就是中国的version, 他们的qq好像是ok的。 我等一下,重新常识下载software center version

Comment: I have an idea that might be useful. There are android emulators for Linux. I will try to install android version of QQ to emulator and see how that works. When I figure this out, I will post an answer. Check back here in couple of days

Answer (score 5):

QQ for linux has been stopped and not supported for  a long time already. There are implementations of [QQ in WINE](http://linux-wiki.cn/wiki/Wine_QQ) for Deepin and Ubuntu Kylin, but there is no (at least no more) Linux-version QQ.

There is also w.qq.com, which is a web-based version of QQ, however it's very limited

Basic idea of my solution is to install [Genymotion](https://www.genymotion.com/#!/) （ an Android emulator ) and install the Android version of QQ in there. Basic steps are: 1)install VirtualBox; 2) install genymotion; 2) add a device; 3) launch that device; 4) download *.apk file for mobile qq; 5) drag and drop to running android emulator

**Step 1 Install VirtualBox**

Genymotion uses VirtualBox as backend for virtualization. It will be important to install it.

Go to https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Linux_Downloads  and download VirtualBox version for your OS version.

If your OS is 32 bit, download i386 package. If your os is 64 bit - install AMD64 package. (You can find out if you use 32 or 64 bit OSwith the `arch` or `uname -m` command; x86_64 means 64 bit, i368 and i686 mean 32 bit).

Drag and drop the downloaded package to Software Center or open the terminal, go to the directory where the package is located with `cd directory-name` and  install the downloaded package with `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-*.deb`

For example, my Ubuntu 14.04 is 64 bit, so I downloaded `virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb`; it is saved in my Downloads folder. I install it with `sudo dpkg -i virtualbox-5.0_5.0.2-102096~Ubuntu~trusty_amd64.deb`

**Step 2 Install Genymotion**

Go to https://www.genymotion.com/ and create account. Genymotion for personal use is free. Download appropriate package for your OS version at https://www.genymotion.com/#!/download

Open the terminal and go to the directory where you downloaded the package. The installation binary will be something like this `genymotion-2.5.2_x64.bin`. In terminal , do `chmod 755 genymotion-*.bin && ./genymotion-*.bin -d $HOME`. There will be new directory created, called `genymotion` in your home directory.

If you prefer to install somewhere else, you can do `./genymotion-* -d /path/to/your/directory`

**Step 3 Install virtual Android Phone**

Go to the folder where you installed Genymotion, launch it. Click ADD button. Select any android version, install it. Once installation is done, select that device and click START to launch it.

**Step 4 Download and Install Android QQ version**

From your Ubuntu web browser to http://im.qq.com/download/ and download the mobile version of QQ. The file should be `mobileqq_android.apk`

Open the file manager. Find the `mobileqq_android.apk` file. Drag and drop it into the running Android emulator.

If you receive an error about incompatible CPU, go back to Step 3 and try different device version.

**Step 5  Create a Desktop Shortcut [optional]**

Open text editor and create `genymotion.desktop`. Contents are the following

```
[Desktop Entry]
Type=Application
Name=Genymotion
Exec=/home/user/genymotion/genymotion
Terminal=false
```

Save that file to desktop. In terminal , do `chmod 755 $HOME/Desktop/genymotion.desktop`

`Exec=` line is important. Make sure it says your actual username, instead of `user`.

References:

https://www.genymotion.com/#!/developers/user-guide

[How can I install a .bin file?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/15093/how-can-i-install-a-bin-file)

[An easy way to create a desktop shortcut?](https://askubuntu.com/q/450266/295286)

Comment: You can also use this http://web2.qq.com/webqq.html

Comment: Please post your answer also in English mode. Thanks

Comment: Can't test it, but+1 for the effort :)