# Can you download Android applications with Ubuntu?

Tags: software-installation, software-recommendation, android

I just want to know if you can, and what kind of applications can be downloaded.

Comment: You can download them but to run them is a different story.

Comment: I've tried this without much success but it looks promising: http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/09/install-android-apps-ubuntu-archon

Answer (score 0):

You could try the method described in the [link](http://www.omgubuntu.co.uk/2014/09/install-android-apps-ubuntu-archon) posted by mchid above. If that doesn't work for you, you could also run Android-x86 in a virtual machine, as described [here](http://www.howtogeek.com/164570/how-to-install-android-in-virtualbox/).

Comment: Please, *please*, ***please*** don't just post links! They're known to go defunct and cause your answer to become completely useless. Here at AskUbuntu, we strive to make a permanently accessible archive of information that can be reached at any time -- if a link dies, your answer is essentially useless. It's far better to summarize the link in the post, and then link back to the original source(s).

Answer (score 0):

Natively ? No. Through Android emulator ? Yes. You will need to download `apk` files for that , though (same as `exe` for Windows apps).

For instance, I've used [Genymotion to install Chinese chatting client QQ](https://askubuntu.com/a/540894/295286)

Comment: But where can I get an apk version? Isn't that for beta testing only. What if this specific app I wanna download doesn't have an apk version