# How to use QQ and WeChat on Ubuntu 16.04 LTS?

Tags: 16.04

How can I install and use QQ and WeChat with Ubuntu 16.04 LTS? Are there any solutions or suggestions?

Comment: QQ for Linux has not been supported for very very long time.  I found a workaround by using android version of QQ in emulator, so you can check out this : http://askubuntu.com/a/540894/295286  As for wechat, wx.qq.com is appropriate solution. It requires you to scan Qr code with your phone. I know this is not the best, but wechat doesn't provide anything better, even for Windows

Comment: Now, you can install offical QQ [there](https://im.qq.com/linuxqq/download.html).

Answer (score 4, accepted):

## WeChat

### Franz

You could use [Franz](http://meetfranz.com/) and configure your WeChat account there.

[image]

It supports:

- Slack
- Messenger (Facebook)
- WhatsApp
- Telegram
- Skype
- WeChat
- Hipchat
- ChatWork
- Flowdock
- Hangouts
- GroupMe
- Rocket.chat
- Mattermost
- Grape
- Gitter
- TweetDeck
- DingTalk
- Steam Chat
- Discord
- MySMS

so far with 3.0.0 and is available for Windows, Linux and OSX.

## QQ

I don't know what QQ is - so can't comment on this.

Comment: wow , so cool thnk u vry much.

And Instant messaging (IM) QQ is China’s largest instant messaging service.

And I found the answer， QQ Chat for facebook. It allows Facebook users to connect and chat with over 780 million monthly active user accounts on Tencent’s instant messenger.

Comment: @Mike.Lee good to hear it helps. If your question is solved with my answer - please mark the answer as accepted.

Comment: Funny thing: WeChat was [created by the owners of QQ](http://www.chinainternetwatch.com/5383/is-tencents-wechat-killing-its-own-qq/).

Comment: This is just the equivalent of visiting https://web.wechat.com/.  In particular, it doesn't support key features the Windows desktop app offers, such as video calling. (As far as I can tell there's no better solution than installing the windows desktop client with wine)

Comment: WeChat in Franz and WeChat in Webbrowser seem not to work under Linux. I use Lubuntu 16.04 LTS and get the message that I should try the web version under Windows or Mac OS.

Answer (score 2):

One way is to install WeChat is a third-party WeChat client for Linux called electronic-wechat.

1. Go to https://github.com/geeeeeeeeek/electronic-wechat/releases
2. Download the file for your architecture, either `linux-ia32.tar.gz` or `linux-x64.tar.gz`
3. Extract the file with `tar xvf linux-ia32.tar.gz` or `tar xvf linux-x64.tar.gz`
4. Go to the directory with the extracted file and run `./electronic-wechat`

Comment: While the link may be helpful, it's better to include essential information into your answer. I suggest you edit the post, because as it stands right now it is of low quality and may be deleted

Comment: Electronic wechat stopped working recently with this error message:  

"For account security, newly registered WeChat accounts are unable to log in to Web WeChat. To use WeChat on a computer, use Windows WeChat or Mac WeChat at http://wechat.com"

Comment: ya right. that link is not working

Answer (score 1):

## QQ

I'd like to suggest Wine QQ.

First download it from [ubuntukylin](http://www.ubuntukylin.com/application/show.php?lang=cn&id=279)(it's a modified version of Ubuntu by Chinese) and extract the files.

Cd into the folder, and install all the **deb**s using following commands:

```
sudo dpkg –i DEB_PACKAGE
```

For those who encounter dependencies unmet:

```
sudo apt-get -f  install ./wine-qqintl_0.1.3-2_i386.deb
```

Answer (score 1):

Installing electronic-wechat works for me.

```
sudo apt install snapd snapd-xdg-open
sudo snap install electronic-wechat
```

Comment: Electronic-wechat stopped working recently, with this error message: `For account security, newly registered WeChat accounts are unable to log in to Web WeChat. To use WeChat on a computer, use Windows WeChat or Mac WeChat at http://wechat.com`

Comment: @YanKingYin That's sad. Is there any plan to develop Linux Wechat?

Comment: Nothing I've heard so far.  Maybe a temporary solution is to use Windows WeChat with Wine.  I will try that later...

Comment: WeChat 2.6.2.27 for Windows works in Wine (as of May 2018)

Comment: https://ferrolho.github.io/blog/2018-12-22/wechat-desktop-on-linux

Comment: @HenriqueFerrolho your comment should be marked as correct answer. It is the only way I could install wechat on Ubuntu 18.04

Answer (score 1):

> Install WeChat Success

### 0x01、 My environment

1. Ubuntu 18.04
2. [wine-4.0](https://www.winehq.org/)
3. WeChat2.6.7.57

### 0x02、 My operate

#### 2.1、 First Failed Operate **(About □)**

1. install update wine to 4.0
2. install WeChat direct
3. all text is □ □ □ □ □
4. [fix □ ,By edit WeChat.desktop file](https://github.com/hillwoodroc/winetricks-zh/issues/66)
   file path:`~/.local/share/applications/wine/Programs/WeChat/WeChat.desktop`

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   ...
   Exec=env WINEPREFIX="/home/tom/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/tom/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/WeChat.lnk
   ...
   ```

   to

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   ...
   Exec=env LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8 WINEPREFIX="/home/tom/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/tom/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/WeChat.lnk
   ...
   ```
5. Now , I can read and send msg,but My write panel don't show my writed text

#### 2.2、 Second Failed Operate

I wont to fix the problem that write panel not't show text ,i do that:

1. open my Windows 10
2. copy `C:\Windows\SysWOW64\riched20.dll` to `.wine/drive_c/windows/syswow64\riched20.dll`
3. copy `C:\Windows\System32\riched20.dll` to `.wine/drive_c/windows/system32/riched20.dll`
4. reopen WeChat,but **failed**

#### 2.3、 Success Operate

1. after `2.1`、`2.2` , I unInstall WeChat
2. download qq.exe、tim.exe and install them
3. download `wechat.exe` and install it
4. fix `wechat.desktop` to :

   ```
   [Desktop Entry]
   Name=WeChat
   Exec=env LC_ALL=zh_CN.UTF-8 WINEPREFIX="/home/tom/.wine" wine C:\\\\windows\\\\command\\\\start.exe /Unix /home/tom/.wine/dosdevices/c:/users/Public/Desktop/WeChat.lnk
   Type=Application
   StartupNotify=true
   Path=/home/tom/.wine/dosdevices/c:/Program Files (x86)/Tencent/WeChat
   Icon=06F2_WeChat.0
   StartupWMClass=wechat.exe
   Name[en_US]=WeChat_1.desktop
   ```
5. copy `.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Tencent/TIM/Bin/RICHED20.DLL` to `.wine/drive_c/Program Files (x86)/Tencent/WeChat/RICHED20.DLL`
6. about wine config

   - open winetricks
   - `select the default wineprefix` (click ok)
   - `install a Windows DLL or component` (click ok)
   - check `riched20`、`riched30`、`richtx32` (click ok)
7. open my WeChat

#### 2.4、 I don't know why

but my WeChat can work well now

1. read 、 write msg
2. send and download file
3. *Screenshot and send picture* **filed** ，but i install `deepin Screenshot` fix it

### 0x03、 Reference

1. [about □ □ □ □](https://github.com/hillwoodroc/winetricks-zh/issues/66)
2. [about write panel 1](https://www.cnblogs.com/makefile/p/wine-life.html)
3. [about write panel 2](https://www.crossovercn.com/thread-18.htm)

Answer (score -2):

1. I found this

[Deepin-Apps-Installation](https://github.com/Jactor-Sue/Deepin-Apps-Installation/blob/master/docs/README-en.md)

> This repo shows how to install apps packaged with deepin-wine by Deepin on Ubuntu based linux distributions, like Wechat, QQ, TIM, Thunder Speed etc.

2. Maybe you don't need to install the software, since they both have web-based versions:

   - [WeChat](https://wx.qq.com/)
   - [QQ](https://web2.qq.com/)

Comment: <error><ret>1203</ret><message>For account security, newly registered WeChat accounts are unable to log in to WeChat for Web. To use WeChat on a computer, you can download WeChat for Windows or WeChat for Mac at http://wechat.com</message></error>

Comment: You may have to wait because the error comes from WeChat servers likely @Sergio