# How to install Genymotion on Ubuntu 14.04 LTS?

Tags: software-installation, genymotion

I'm using Ubuntu 14.04 LTS, 32 bits and I want to install Genymotion.

But when I go to the official Genymotion's website to download its packages, I see that there is only Genymotion 2.7.2 with support for Ubuntu 15.10 (Wily Werewolf) or above (64bit).

So do you know if there is any other Genymotion version that I can install?

Comment: Seems like you have to upgrade. 32bit is limitating to 3GB RAM

Comment: @MAKRipon NO, it is clearly Not a Duplicate . The question is about installing Genymotion on 14.04 (where they are providing .deb for only 15 and later) , the question to which you are pointing doesn't even have the word "Genymotion" in it.

Comment: Installation of genymotion has been part of my answer to another question ,but the question isnt a duplicate. See if this helps:   http://askubuntu.com/a/540894/295286

Comment: I'm pretty sure they used to have 32 bit version. Perhaps they've removed support for it. It's been a common move by many companies lately