# Problem occurs when installing QQ in Android enumeration created by Genymotion

Tags: 16.04, software-installation, android, genymotion

So I followed ([How to install QQ on Ubuntu 14.04?](https://askubuntu.com/questions/540875/how-to-install-qq-on-ubuntu-14-04)), @Serg answer. In step 4, I received an error which is

```
An error occured while deploying the file.
This probably means that the app contains ARM native code 
and your Genymotion device cannot run ARM instructions. 
You should either build your native code to x86 or install an ARM 
translation tool in your device.
```

I don't have 50 reputations to ask @Serg under the comment section but I need to use QQ as soon as possible. So I'll ask here. Anyone can help me with this problem?

Comment: If you need to use it ASAP do not overcomplicate things: http://web2.qq.com/webqq.html . Regarding your error message please pay attention to the last paragraph in step 4 - *If you receive an error about incompatible CPU, go back to Step 3 and try different device version* -, because you obviously selected x86 where you should have selected an ARM one. The goal is to run the Android version via an Android (ARM) VM/Emulation provided by Genymotion.

Comment: webqq cannot transfer screenshots, and I tried multiple Android version and all didn't work. Is there a way to tell which one is ARM one? I searched online, this passage confuses me, is Genomotion removed ARM? (https://forum.xda-developers.com/showthread.php?t=2528952)

Comment: Indeed, it needs this: https://gist.github.com/wbroek/9321145 . For device choose a known phone with Android 5.0+, not a tablet. I'm not sure about the legality of the required file though. So, not attempting an answer and this comment may have to be deleted.

Comment: Wow I tried it, it's working, Thank you very much!!!

Comment: Nice to know there's alternative solution. If i recall correctly , i got around it by trying different device version, so I ended up with QQ working on Sony Experia emulator, but aside from that wasn't aware of other ways

Comment: @Serg yeah that worked haha!